# Later.js throwing a.getTime is not a function when using isValid function on a composite Schedule

Tags: javascript, node.js, laterjs

I started using Later.js Library recently and am facing this issue on using 'isValid' function on a composite Schedule. Since I am new to this, I am likely making some common mistake. Please guide for the same. I am adding the code snippet and the error message below.

```
var schedule = 

later.parse.recur()
.on(25).dayOfMonth().on(5).month().on(2016).year()
.and()
.on(26).dayOfMonth().on(5).month().on(2016).year()
.and()
.on(27).dayOfMonth().on(5).month().on(2016).year()

var sched = later.schedule(schedule);
var ans = sched.isValid(new Date('2016-05-27'));
console.log(ans);
```

Here is the error message

```
f:\Projects\DragonFly\node_modules\later\later.js:777
return !b || a.getTime() > b.getTime();
^


TypeError: a.getTime is not a function
at f:\Projects\DragonFly\node_modules\later\later.js:777:24
at findNext (f:\Projects\DragonFly\node_modules\later\later.js:785:23)
at getInstances (f:\Projects\DragonFly\node_modules\later\later.js:637:52)
at Object.later.schedule.sched.isValid (f:\Projects\DragonFly\node_modules\later\later.js:793:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (f:\Projects\DragonFly\Controllers\scheduleController.js:76:17)
```

I updated my Later.js to the latest version with no success. Please tell me if I am making any mistake in the code, or is it a bug in the library itself?

Comment: This looks like a bug. I would suggest bringing it to the attention of the developer.

Comment: yeah, I opened an issue for the same on github.